# Домен и балансировщик нагрузки

Tags: http, ssl, https, dns, amazon-web-services

у меня есть домен example.com и сертификат SSL для него. есть ELB балансировщик нагрузки амазон без защиты SSL. мне надо чтобы пользователи с помощью протокола ХТТПС обращались к домену example.com и получали ответ сгенерированный ELB. как мне это сделать?

Comment: Нужно получить сертификат для домена (например в AWS Certificate Manager) и к балансировщику [добавить HTTPS Listener](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html).

Comment: План А - поднять в балансировщике HTTPS. План Б - поднять инстанс с nginx, в котором установить сертификат и сделать proxy_pass на ELB. Но этот план обойдётся гораздо дороже - дополнительный инстанс плюс трафик этого инстанса,